# Getting started with 'No SQL' Cloud DB , Which one is better to learn???

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, nosql

I'm currently working on Codeigniter-MySQL.

Now i want to learn some 'No SQL' Cloud DataBase. Which one is good to start with. It should be easy to use with my php, codeigniter projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use the regular active record class in ci, cos the structure is all different.

However, theres definitely evidence of people getting [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) to work in CodeIgniter.
theres a library [here](https://bitbucket.org/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongo-library/wiki/Home).

Comment: K, I'll start with MongoDB. Is there any difference between this and Cassandra???...